# Linq query to join 4 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join

I have a table called deliveries with columns id,shiftid, occurrence,delfee).  I have three other tables delcash,delcc,delsplit.  Del cash has columns (id,cost,paid), delcc has columns (id,cccost,ccpaid,cashtip), delsplit has columns(id,cashcost,cashpaid,cccost,ccpaid). The id links the delivery entries to one of the three other tables based on the type of payment.  I am trying to get a list where the tables are joined together in a way so i can iterate through a list and get a table in a view that shows each delivery in order of occurrence as well as the tip and delivery fee of each delivery.  Any idea if it is possible to do this?  Or should I just use SQL?

```
SELECT deliveries.occurrence, deliveries.delfee,delcash.cost,delcash.paid,delcc.cost,delcc.paid,delcc.cashtip,
delsplit.cashcost,delsplit.cashpaid,delsplit.cccost,delsplit.ccpaid
FROM deliveries
LEFT JOIN delcash
ON deliveries.id = delcash.id
LEFT JOIN delcc
ON deliveries.id = delcc.id
LEFT JOIN delsplit
ON deliveries.id = delsplit.id
```

Comment: Are you using Entity-Framework with this?

Comment: Yes I am using entity

Comment: Can you state or give what are the Foreign key from each table.

Comment: a delivery has one of three kinds of possible payments, cash, credit or split.  So the id in the delivery table to the foreign key(id) in one of the other three tables(delcash,delcc,delsplit)

Comment: `delcash.cost,delcash.paid,delcc.cost,delcc.paid,delcc.cashtip,
delsplit.cashcost,delsplit.cashpaid,delsplit.cccost,delsplit.ccpaid` if you'll select these items, this will sometimes gives you null values with other fields.

Comment: Yes it has some null values in every column but they wont get displayed any way i need to find the tip, delfee, and payment type and display that to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class and let the three cost tables inherit from this class then you can apply the Table per Concrete Type strategy for mapping the tables.

see:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

OR redesign your database and apply Table per type strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var joinedDel = from delivery in tblDeliveries
                join delC in tblDelCash on delivery.id equals delC.id
                join delCC in tblDelCreditCard on delivery.id equals delCC.id
                join delSplit in tblDelSplit on delivery.id equals delSplit.id
                select new {
                      //Then create a new instance of Anonymous object where you will set all values of its properties
                      //For example, you can set ShiftID = delivery.ShiftID
                };
```

I will also suggest to normalize first your tables(see this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for your reference) . This will give you more understanding on how will you join those tables properly.

Comment: I thought the way I have those tables set up is normalized?  If not could you give a concrete example of how to correctly normalize them?

Comment: I have someting very similar to what you have listed there except it looks like this: from deliveries in db.deliveries
join delcashes in db.delcashes
on deliveries.id equals delcashes.id
join delccs in db.delccs
on deliveries.id equals delccs.id
join delsplits in db.delsplits
on deliveries.id equals delsplits.id
select new deliverylistitem() thew variance in names is from the names generated by visual studio when creating models.

Comment: Can you give what are the properties that you required with your joined tables?? Just like with SQL, you need to select what are the fields that you need to include with that. For example, You need `id`, `ShiftId`, `Occurence` and `Delete` details. Yes, you can create a new instance of `DeliveryListItem` object and just set its properties. The use of anonymous object will just give your code flexibility to set different properties that you can't be found on the defined object.

Comment: I added the query I want in SQL to my original post.