# Linq Lambda multiple tables ( 4 tables ) LEFT JOIN

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have 4 tables;

```
TMain >> MainId (PK)

T1 >> T1_Id, MainId, X (PK and FK) X is decimal

T2 >> T2_Id, MainId, X (PK and FK) X is decimal

T3 >> T3_Id, MainId, X (PK and FK) X is decimal
```

Here SQL output;

```
SELECT TMain.*, (ISNULL(T1.X,0) + ISNULL(T2.X,0) + ISNULL(T3.X,0)) AS TOTAL FROM TMain

LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 ON TMain.MainId = T1.MainId

LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON TMain.MainId = T2.MainId

LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON TMain.MainId = T3.MainId
```

How can I write it **LINQ LAMDA**

```
   var AbbA = MyContext.TMain
                    .GroupJoin(
                        MyContext.T1,
                        q1 => q1.TMainId,
                        q2 => q2.TMainId,
                        (x, y) => new { A = x, T1_A = y })
                            .SelectMany(
                            xy => xy.T1_A.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (x, y) => new { A = x.A, T1_A = y })
                    .GroupJoin(
                        MyContext.T2,
                        q1 => q1.A.TMainId,
                        q2 => q2.TMainId,
                        (x, y) => new { A = x, T2_A = y })
                            .SelectMany(
                            xy => xy.T2_A.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (x, y) => new { A = x.A, T2_A = y })
                    .GroupJoin(
                        MyContext.T3,
                        q1 => q1.A.A.TMainId,
                        q2 => q2.TMainId,
                        (x, y) => new { A = x, T3_A = y })
                            .SelectMany(
                            xy => xy.T3_A.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (x, y) => new { A = x.A, T3_A = y })
                    .Select(q => new 
                    {
                        TMainId = q.A.A.A.TMainId,
                        Total = (q.T3_A.X == null ? 0 : q.T3_A.X) +
                                (q.A.T2_A.X == null ? 0 : q.A.T2_A.X) +
                                (q.A.A.T1_A.X == null ? 0 : q.A.A.T1_A.X),
                    }).ToList();
```

So I want to access T1 fields or TMain fields

I wrote q.A.A.T1_A.X or q.A.A.A. in linq select

Is that true? or have simplest way?

Comment: try see [101 LINQ Samples: Join Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply I found some answers but not LAMBDA
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049586/linq-query-to-join-4-tables

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test now if will work, but sometimes you can write the GroupJoin like (if you expect 0 or N registers from T1):

```
.GroupJoin(MyContext.T1,
     q1 => q1.TMainId,
     q2 => q2.TMainId,
     (x, y) => new { A = x, T1_A = y.DefaultIfEmpty() })
```

or (if you expect 0 or 1 registers from T1)

```
.GroupJoin(MyContext.T1,
     q1 => q1.TMainId,
     q2 => q2.TMainId,
     (x, y) => new { A = x, T1_A = y.FirstOrDefault() })
```

It always depends what do you like to return for the next lambda, and in this case you don't need the SelectMany(). But this code will be the most simple left join you can get with linq/lambda if you cannot map accordingly the relationship between the tables.

You can simplify if you map the relationship between table TMain and T1 with "HasOptional", like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T1>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.TMain)
            .WithMany(y => y.T1s)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TMaidId);
```

The "HasOptional()" shows to Entity Framework that this relationship are optional, so the LEFT JOIN will be used to mount the query. If you use "HasRequired()", will be used the JOIN.

So, you can use Include():

```
var AbbA = MyContext.TMain
     .Include(x => x.T1s)
```

To left join T1 and T2:

```
var AbbA = MyContext.TMain
     .Include(x => x.T1s.Select(y => y.T2s))
```